# How can I see a list of snippets in my Vim?

Tags: gvim, functions, plugin-ultisnips, snippets, plugin-snipmate

I installed `vim-snippets`, `ultisnips` and `coc.nvim` in my Vim (gVim on Windows).

How can I see a list of snippets that I can use in my current open file?

For example, when I'm editing a `.js` file, I want to see the list of all snippets for javascript file.

I found `UltiSnips#SnippetsInCurrentScope` in this [link](https://github.com/SirVer/ultisnips/blob/master/doc/UltiSnips.txt#:%7E:text=3.4.3-,UltiSnips%23SnippetsInCurrentScope,-*UltiSnips%23SnippetsInCurrentScope) in ultisnips github repository but I do not know how can I use that in _vimrc file.

I know I can see list of snippets in [vim-snippets github repository](https://github.com/honza/vim-snippets/tree/master/UltiSnips) but I want to see them in my Vim.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Coc Snippet Provider

If you are using [coc](https://github.com/neoclide/coc.nvim) you can install the [coc-snippets](https://github.com/neoclide/coc-snippets) plugin that provides a snippet provider and auto-completion of snippets.

You can install the snippet provider using the following Vim command:

```
:CocInstall coc-snippets
```

### Fuzzy Providers

If you are using the [FZF](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf.vim) plugin it provides a `:Snippets` command that list of the UlitSnip snippets available.

If you are using the [Clap](https://github.com/liuchengxu/vim-clap) plugin it is probably possible to build a provider for UltiSnip snippets using the API that you mention in your question.

Comment: Thanks, your answer solved my problem.